# Run multiple CLI commands inside ONE child process, but HANDLE each output separately in Node

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I need to execute a batch CLI commands inside the only in one child process.
For example, suppose i have these shell commands:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

As i know, the `child_process.exec` not really fits in my case because it will create child process per command. I could concatenate these commands via `&&` and run as a shell script via `child_process.spawn` - but, again, my purpose is to **handle each command separately**, not just like the whole shell script.

Thanks for any suggestions and tips.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i can send commands to the `child_process.spawn` process:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const shell = spawn('sh');

shell.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

shell.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(data.toString());
});

function sendCommand(command) {
  shell.stdin.write(command + '\n');
}

sendCommand('echo 1');
sendCommand('echo 2');
sendCommand('echo 3');

shell.stdin.end();
```

That's exactly what i need.